# Dúvida sobre Relacionamento Many-to-Many EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou com dúvida em uma seguinte Regra: 
Tenho N Produtos e N Moedas. 
Desse relacionamento irei ter a tabela ProdutoMoeda:

```
ProdutoMoeda
Id -  ProdutoId - MoedaID - Nome
1     2           1         ProdutoNome + MoedaNome
2     1           1         ProdutoNome + MoedaNome
3     2           2         ProdutoNome + MoedaNome
```

Também tenho um  Correspondente que comercializa N ProdutoMoeda. Porém Correspondente possui também N Lojas que comercializa o N ProdutoMoeda que está vinculado ao Correspondente.
A loja só pode vender os produtos que foram cadastrado ao Correspondente, visto que a loja depende do Correspondente também.

Ex: Correspondente Walmart Comercializa - Produto Espécie e Cartão - nas Moedas USD e BRL.
   A Loja 1 - que pertence ao Correspondente Walmart só pode cadastrar 1 ou N produtos que o Walmart comercializa.

[image: Ficaria assim:]

Seria certo criar uma Pk pra uma tabela que foi gerada de um N-N e usar como chave de relacionamento em outra tabela? Estou tentando representar isso no EF também mas logo quando vou relacionar Correspondente e ProdutoMoeda utilizando ProdutoCorrespondente já me gera alguns errors.
Usei o mesmo exemplo para mapear ProdutoMoeda e deu certo, mas pra usar o relacionamento dela com ProdutoCorrespondente me da erro:

```
ProdutoCorrespondente_ProdutoMoeda_Target_ProdutoCorrespondente_ProdutoMoeda_Source: : The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical.
```

O map ta assim:

```
public ProdutoCorrespondenteConfig()
    {

        HasKey(x => new { x.ProdutoCorrespondenteId, x.ProdutoMoedaId, x.CorrespondenteId });

        Property(x => x.ProdutoCorrespondenteId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        Property(t => t.Nome)
           .IsRequired()
           .HasMaxLength(60);

        HasRequired(x => x.ProdutoMoeda)
            .WithMany(x => x.ProdutosCorrespondente)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ProdutoMoedaId);

        HasRequired(x => x.Correspondente)
            .WithMany(x => x.ProdutosCorrespondente)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.CorrespondenteId);

    }
```

Comment: Allan, achei esse link de um cara que tem uma dúvida semelhante a sua, não se resolve seu problema. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754842/how-to-fix-the-number-of-properties-in-the-dependent-and-principal-roles-in-a-r`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Seria certo criar uma Pk pra uma tabela que foi gerada de um N-N e usar como chave de relacionamento em outra tabela?

Sim, mas não é assim que você vai conseguir:

```
HasKey(x => new { x.ProdutoCorrespondenteId, x.ProdutoMoedaId, x.CorrespondenteId });
```

A modelagem recomendada é assim:

```
public class ProdutoCorrespondente
{
    [Key]
    public int ProdutoCorrespondenteId { get; set; }
    [Index("IUQ_ProdutoCorrespondente_ProdutoMoedaId_CorrespondenteId", IsUnique = true, Order = 1)]
    public int ProdutoMoedaId { get; set; }
    [Index("IUQ_ProdutoCorrespondente_ProdutoMoedaId_CorrespondenteId", IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]
    public int CorrespondenteId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(60)]
    public String Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual ProdutoMoeda ProdutoMoeda { get; set; }
    public virtual Correspondente Correspondente { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Opa, Vlw Cigano.
Deixei apenas ProdutoCorrespondenteId, e ele já criou os index para os outros campos. Abraços!